# Evaluating postfix expression using stacks in java

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I am trying to write a code for postfix evaluation but I get a error as

java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer and the problem is in the lines`obj1=(int) calStack.topAndpop();`.The problem is my ArrayStack topAndpop() method returns a **Object** type as

```
 public Object topAndpop() throws EmptyStackException{
    Object returnPop;
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyStackException("Stack empty");
        else{ 
            returnPop=top();
            pop();
            }
        return returnPop;
```

and I should be able to convert this into int type.I can't see anything wrong apart from this line.Can someone point me how to correct this please

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class Calculate{
    double result=0;
    int obj1,obj2;
    public Object cal(String expression) throws OverFlowException,EmptyStackException{

    String[] array = expression.split("");//remember
    // for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        // System.out.println(array[i]);
    ArrayStack calStack=new ArrayStack(array.length);
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(!(array[i].equals("+") || array[i].equals("-")||array[i].equals("/") || array[i].equals("*"))){
            calStack.push(array[i]);
        //calStack.print();
        }
        else {

            obj1=(int) calStack.topAndpop();//check how this casting is done
            obj2=(int)calStack.topAndpop();
        result=calculate(obj2,obj1,array[i]);
        System.out.println(result);
        calStack.push(result);
        }
    }
    return calStack.topAndpop();

}
public double calculate(int a,int b,String op){
    if(op=="+")
        return a+b;
    else if(op=="-")
        return a-b;
    else if(op=="/")
        return a/b;
    else if (op=="^")
        return Math.pow(a,b);
    else 

        return a*b;

}

public static void main (String args[]) throws OverFlowException,EmptyStackException{
    Calculate c=new Calculate();
    System.out.println("result"+c.cal("623+-382/+*2^3"));

}
```

}

Comment: try printing out what you are popping from the stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
obj1=(int) calStack.topAndpop();//check how this casting is done
obj2=(int)calStack.topAndpop();
```

Use:

```
obj1 = Integer.parseInt((String)calStack.topAndpop());
obj2 = Integer.parseInt((String)calStack.topAndpop());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more then one issue, first String equality -

```
public double calculate(int a,int b,String op){
  if(op.equals("+")) // <-- .equals! Not ==
    return a+b;
  else if(op.equals("-"))
    return a-b;
  else if(op.equals("/"))
    return a/b;
  else if(op.equals("^"))
    return Math.pow(a,b);
  else 
    return a*b;
}
```

Next, since your Stack doesn't appear to be [generic](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/stack-unbound.html), you should call [Integer.parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29),

```
obj1 = Integer.parseInt(calStack.topAndpop().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the if condition where you check for symbols, In this you have missed the `^` symbol :

```
         if(!(array[i].equals("+") || array[i].equals("-")
              ||array[i].equals("/") || array[i].equals("*"))){
```

Add the condition for `^` symbol as follows and your code will work :

```
          if(!(array[i].equals("+") 
               || array[i].equals("-")
               ||array[i].equals("/") 
               || array[i].equals("*"))
               || array[i].equals("^"))){

            // do something 
          }
```

Comment: Thanks spotted that after posting

Comment: Was this the cause of the issue..or was it something else ?